# Code Igniter Pagination and JQuery action

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am creating a book management web application and I have problem deleting a book when I use pagination.

In my controller I have this code:

```
<?php
class Books extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
                #$this->load->model('books_model');
                $this->load->helper('path');
    }

        function index() {

            $config['base_url'] = base_url().'books/index';
            $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('tbl_books');
            $config['per_page'] = 2;

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            $data['books'] = $this->db->get('tbl_books',$config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
            $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
            $data['page'] = 'Books';
            $this->load->view('books_view', $data);
        }

}
?>
```

in my books_view I have this code:

```
        <p class="pagination ta-right">
    <?=$pagination?>
    </p>
    <?php foreach($books->result() as $row): ?>
            <a href="<?=base_url()?><?=$row->image?>" class="nyroModal"> <img src="<?=base_url()?><?=$row->image?>" alt="" /></a>
            <a href="#<?=$row->id?>" title="<?=$row->title?>" class="nyroModal"><b class="big"><?=$row->title?></b></a> &middot; 
    <?php
      $sql = $this->db->query("select * from tbl_transactions where bookid=".$row->id." and (type='reserve' or type='borrowed')");
      $book_info = $sql->result();
            if($sql->num_rows() > 0) {
                    if($book_info[0]->type == 'reserve') { ?>
                           <span class="label label-red">Reserved</span>
                      <?php }elseif($book_info[0]->type == 'borrowed') { ?>
                            <span class="label label-blue">Borrowed</span>
                      <?php } else { ?>
                            <span class="label label-green">Available</span>
                      <?php }
                      } else { ?>
                            <span class="label label-green">Available</span>
                      <?php } ?>
                            Author: <b><?=$row->authors?></b> |  Category: </small><br/>
                      <div id="action-<?=$row->id?>">
                            <a href="" id="remove-<?=$row->id?>">remove</a> &middot; <a href="#">edit</a>
                      </div>
                            <img src="<?=base_url()?>img/small-loader.gif" style="display:none;" id="ajax-load-<?=$row->id?>" />
                 <div id="<?=$row->id?>" style='display: none;'><h3><?=$row->title?></h3><p align="justify"><?=$row->description?></p></div>
                     <?php endforeach; } ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
<?php foreach($books->result() as $row): ?>
    $('#remove-<?=$row->id?>').click(function() {
        var stats = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?');

        if(stats) {

                        $('#action-<?=$row->id?>').hide();
                        $('#ajax-load-<?=$row->id?>').show();

                        $.ajax({
                         type: 'POST',
                         url: "<?=base_url()?>bookacts/delbook/",
                         data: ({id: <?=$row->id?>}),
                         cache: false,
                         success: function (msg){

                           if(msg == ""){
                                $('#ajax-load-<?=$row->id?>').hide();
                                $('.box-error').fadeIn("slow");
                                $('#action-<?=$row->id?>').fadeIn();
                            } else {
                                $('#ajax-load-<?=$row->id?>').hide();
                                $('.box-success').fadeIn("slow")
                                                 .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 2000)
                                                 .fadeOut('slow');
                                $('#action-<?=$row->id?>').fadeIn();
                            }
                         }
                        }); return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    });
<?php endforeach; ?>
});
</script>
```

My problem is that the code only deletes the entry when I am on page 2 onwards.  But when I am on page 1 the script just don't work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the problem right away. However in my opinion you're using both CodeIgniter and Jquery wrong, so I will just give you some hints.

First of all Codeigniter uses a MVC pattern, as you probably know. And a view isn't really meant for SQL. Better yet, most of the times the Controller isn't even used for SQL. You should try to keep the SQL within the models.

Another small Codeigniter thing. I think it's nicer to use:

```
function index($page=0) {
```

And then:

```
$data['books'] = $this->db->get('tbl_books',$config['per_page'], $page);
```

Instead of using $this->uri->segment(3)

Secondly you should use Jquery 'dynamic' too. You're now making a function for every book while you always want to do the same action.

Add a class:

```
<a href="" id="remove-<?=$row->id?>" class="book-remove">remove</a>
```

Then as JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.book-remove').each(function() {
            $(this).click(function() {

            var stats = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?');

            if(stats) {
                var bookID = $(this).attr("id").replace("remove-", "");
                $('#action'+bookID).hide();
                $('#ajax-load-'+bookID).show();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "<?=base_url()?>bookacts/delbook/",
                    data: ({id: bookID}),
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (msg){

                        if(msg == ""){
                            $('#ajax-load-'+bookID).hide();
                            $('.box-error').fadeIn("slow");
                            $('#action-'+bookID).fadeIn();
                        } else {
                            $('#ajax-load-'+bookID).hide();
                            $('.box-success').fadeIn("slow")
                                 .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 2000)
                                 .fadeOut('slow');
                            $('#action-'+bookID).fadeIn();
                        }
                    }
                }); return false;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

However I think even if you change these things, you're problem might be not solved yet. But it's hard to figure out the problem without seeing what it does.

Just view the source if the javascript is correct (with IDs) Check if you even get the JS confirm message. Check if it does the AJAX, make some alerts. Check if there is a javascript error. Etc.

Good luck.